# Prevent unauthenticated Put to S3 bucket with "Block all public access" enabled

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having a bit of trouble preventing "public" (unauthenticated) writes to my S3 bucket. It's quite possible that I'm missing the point, but I would have imagined that enabling the "Block all public access" setting on the S3 bucket would prevent *any* access (including writes). However, using the code below I am still able to create objects in the bucket without supplying any credentials.

```
// s3Client.ts
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const region = "eu-west-2";
const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region,
});

export { s3Client, region };
```

```
export const badS3 = async () => {
  const bucket = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET ?? "some-bucket";
  const key = `this_should_fail.txt`;
  const body = "This is a test";

  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: body
  });
  const result = await s3Client.send(command);
};
```

Executing badS3 creates the file:
[S3 dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zbPW.png)

[Public access blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJunD.png)

I have no bucket policy (though I don't think I should need one, since I've given public access is disabled). ACLs are disabled too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you setup credentials for AWS's CLI, or are you running on a EC2 node with instance credentials?  The SDK will [load credentials from different sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have entered your AWS user access key on the machine you are running this code, the machine will have all the permissions that you have as a user.

Comment: Thanks, I really was missing something obvious!